# Form recognizer 'errors': ['Page 1: Document is either invalid or exceeds the page/size limits.']

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

when I use the Azure Form Recognizer to extract pdf's text, everything is fine when I use the sample data that Microsoft provide. but when I use my only pdf to train the model, I get the following error:

Response status code: 200
Response body:

```
{
    'modelId': '4380f0c6-e073-4a5f-b69e-78e9b7e39c0d',
    'trainingDocuments': [{
        'documentName': 'liste_med_2019_08_15_en - p201.pdf',
        'pages': 1,
        'errors': ['Page 1: Document is either invalid or exceeds the page/size limits.'],
        'status': 'failure'
    }, {
        'documentName': 'liste_med_2019_08_15_en - p202.pdf',
        'pages': 1,
        'errors': ['Page 1: Document is either invalid or exceeds the page/size limits.'],
        'status': 'failure'
    }, {
        'documentName': 'liste_med_2019_08_15_en - p203.pdf',
        'pages': 1,
        'errors': ['Page 1: Document is either invalid or exceeds the page/size limits.'],
        'status': 'failure'
    }, {
        'documentName': 'liste_med_2019_08_15_en - p204.pdf',
        'pages': 1,
        'errors': ['Page 1: Document is either invalid or exceeds the page/size limits.'],
        'status': 'failure'
    }, {
        'documentName': 'liste_med_2019_08_15_en - p205.pdf',
        'pages': 1,
        'errors': ['Page 1: Document is either invalid or exceeds the page/size limits.'],
        'status': 'failure'
    }],
    'errors': [{
        'errorMessage': 'Unable to fit model. No documents clustered.'
    }]
}
```

The training files I use is 5 pdf each one is 1 page and with a similar format.

here is the sample of my pdf:
[image: sample of my pdf]

Please, Could anyone help me fix my problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The general input requirements for documents submitted for training the Form Recognizer API are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/build-training-data-set#general-input-requirements). Could you verify that the total size of your 5 PDF documents does not exceed 4 MB?

Comment: Yes, I can. I am pretty sure that my training files total size are only 515 KB, far less than 4 MB. I have also tried 3 other sample pdf files, all of them are only one page for each and 5 pdf for each training sample, but all my tries are fail. My only success experience is using the sample files that Microsoft provide.

Comment: Is your PDF document password protected by any chance? We cannot extract information from such documents.